# can't connect JDBC driver to Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

I have seen many tutorials but could not find any help. Can we connect Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition (not express. All tutorials are showing express versions) to Java using JDBC drivers? If yes what do we need to download and how to connect. There is no Oracle exe folder in my C: drive as shown in many videos. I checked previously asked questions also couldn't find something helpful.

Comment: How does `can't connect` manifest?

Comment: You need to download the JDBC driver: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbcdriver-ucp-downloads.html see [here](https://mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/) for a tutorial on how to establish a JDBC connection

Comment: no oracleexe folder  or oracle_home folder is created in my C Drive .Will executing OJDBC6.JAR creates that?